# IInvokedMethodListener expects all config and testmethods to be on implementing class

Tags: spring, testng

I am using `IInvokedMethodListener` of TestNG to carryout certain operations after execution of a test method -

```
public class MyListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
   Method testMethod = getClass().getMethod(result.getName());
}

@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
  // some magic here  
}
```

But execution of tests using `mvn test` results in following errors -

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.savingglobal.opsys.webui.util.MyListener.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.savingglobal.opsys.webui.util.MyListener.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod()`

and all of the configuration methods and my test methods. Am I using the listener wrong? I am on TestNG 6.9.10

Comment: You don't give enough context. Could share more code and the full stacktrace ? How do you register your listener ? Could you try to run your test without maven ?

Comment: error is from line ```Method testMethod = getClass().getMethod(result.getName())``` updated the question. Since MyListener does not have springTestContextBeforeTestClass config hence I get this error.  but then how do I get reference of testMethod ?

The error appears when I don't use maven and run test method as TestNG test

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do: `getClass()` will return `MyListener.class` and `result.getName()` MAY return the name of the method. But if you want the executed Method, just use `method.getTestMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()`

Comment: awesome works well, please post it as answer and I would accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caution: `getClass()` will return `MyListener.class` and `result.getName()` **MAY** return the name of the method.

But if you want the executed `Method`, just use `method.getTestMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()`.